# componentDidCatch is not getting called when there is an error in promise

Tags: reactjs, react-fiber

As per the new [react 16 release doc](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html) it says

**"React 16 prints all errors that occurred during rendering to the console in development, even if the application accidentally swallows them."**

I have a **Parent** component and a **Child** component. I have triggered an error in then block of promise. But it will call catch method of the promise, componentDidCatch of parent is not getting called. I am not sure whether this the expected behaviour.

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/john1jan/Luktwrdm/14/

```
class Parent extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={hasError:false}
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.hasError){
      return <div>Something went wrong</div>
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>I am parent</h1>
        <Child></Child>
      </div>
    );
  }
  componentDidCatch(error,errorInfo){
    this.setState({
      hasError:true
    })
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>I am child</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then((response) => {
      throw new Error("I am the error in promise");
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log("Error caught in catch",error);
    })
    ;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent name="world"/>, 
document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Because the error was not in the component, so there is nothing to catch. In fact, you have already caught the exception yourself and chose to log it to the console. If you want to pass it on, simply re-throw the error in your catch.

Comment: the error is in the component life cycle method right ?

Comment: More over the doc says "React 16 prints all errors that occurred during rendering to the console in development, even if the application accidentally swallows them.". What if i forgot to add catch block after then ?

Comment: As soon as you catch an error, the error is considered handled and as such there is no error anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Just want to point out to anyone who comes into this question looking for an answer.

> React 16 prints all errors that occurred during **rendering** to the console in development, even if the application accidentally swallows them.

`componentDidCatch` will only trigger within the rendering lifecycle methods.

Since your error is thrown inside the **promise**. It is **asynchronous** and won't be part of the rendering lifecycle so you will need to handle the error yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You're catching the error and the return of a catch is a promise, so you don't have error anymore, if you remove the .catch on your fetch in componentDidMount, this should work!